# Creating some horizontal space between equations and Right Brace

Tags: biblatex, spacing, brackets, braces

I tried using the following Right Brace type:

```
$$\begin{rcases}
  a &= b + c \\
  d &= e + f + g \\
  h &= i + j + k + l
\end{rcases}$$
```

But I have noticed that the brace is too close to the equations, is there any chance I can create some spacing between the two?

Comment: Add  a horizontal space at the end of each line. Note your code adds an unwanted spacing  between `a, d, h` and the = sign. Aldo, do not use the plain TeX syntax `$$ … $$` for displayed  equations – it results in a bad vertical spacing. Use `\[  … `]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[right=\enspace\empheqrbrace]{align*}
a &= b + c \\
d &= e + f + g \\ 
h &= i + j + k + l 
\end{empheq}
    \vskip 3ex
\[ \begin{rcases}
a &= b + c \\
d &= e + f + g \\
h &= i + j + k + l \;
\end{rcases} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use `rcases` for this, but `aligned`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

This is not the best way to cope with a system
\[
\begin{rcases}
  a &= b + c \\
  d &= e + f + g \\
  h &= i + j + k + l
\end{rcases}
\]
A better way is to use \texttt{aligned} as in the example below
\[
\left.
\begin{aligned}
  a &= b + c \\
  d &= e + f + g \\
  h &= i + j + k + l
\end{aligned}
\right\rbrace
\]
or, if you want some more space next to the brace,
\[
\left.
\begin{aligned}
  a &= b + c \\
  d &= e + f + g \\
  h &= i + j + k + l
\end{aligned}
\;\right\rbrace
\]
Never use \verb|$$| in \LaTeX. Ever.

\end{document}
```

[image]